# Create access token for android from php

Tags: php, android, token

I would secure users accounts with tokens in my android app.
This app uses a PHP REST API to get data.

For the creation of secure tokens I use:

```php
$secret="MySecretKey";
$token=bin2hex(random_bytes(64));
$hashtoken=hash_hmac("sha-256",$token,$secret);
```

Now do I have to send the `$hashtoken` as token for the android app ?
Or do I have to save the hashed token in my database and send the hex token ?

Is this method sufficiently secure if I do not expire the tokens?
Thank for help.

Answer (score 0):

At login time you generate a access token at server end , and save it in database according to user id. After then send this token to app. When API will call from android device this token should be send by android in header section. Every time server will match access token is valid or not.

Comment: Thanks, in the header section I must use :
Authorization : Basic token ? or Bearer token ?
And in server side how i detect the header authorization ?

Comment: Use Authorization and add token in this.
In PHP 
$headerValue = getallheaders();
$AccessToken = $headerValue ['Authorization'];